Export to excel template using laravel
I'm trying to export to a predefined excel template using laravel same as image provided.
i tried every solution from drawing to copy style all didn't work as expected
here's what i've got so far :
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\FollowUp;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomStartCell;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithDrawings;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;


class ExportFollowUp implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithMapping, WithDrawings, WithCustomStartCell, WithEvents
{
    public function startCell(): string
    {
        return 'A3';
    }

    public function drawings()
    {
        $imagePath = str_replace(url('/'), public_path('/'), asset('images/Picture1.jpg'));

        $drawing = new Drawing();
        $drawing->setName('Logo');
        $drawing->setDescription('This is my logo');
        $drawing->setPath($imagePath);
        $drawing->setHeight(30);
        $drawing->setCoordinates('I1');
        $drawing->setOffsetX(0); // Align the image to the left of the cell

        return $drawing;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return FollowUp::select('date', 'time', 'follow_up_type_id', 'follow_up_statement', 'location', 'coordinator', 'prepare', 'status', 'details')->get();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'التاريخ',
            'الوقت',
            'نوع المتابعة',
            'بيان المتابعة',
            'المكان',
            'التنسيق مع',
            'تحضير', 
            'أنجز',
            'ملاحظات',
        ];
    }

    public function map($FollowUp): array
    {
        return [
            $FollowUp->date->format('Y-m-d'),
            $FollowUp->time->format('H:i'),
            $FollowUp->follow_up_type->name,
            $FollowUp->follow_up_statement,
            $FollowUp->location,
            $FollowUp->coordinator,
            $FollowUp->prepare,
            $FollowUp->status == 1 ? 'نعم' : 'كلا',
            $FollowUp->details,
        ];
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $sheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();
                $lastRow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
                $lastColumn = 'I';

                // Set sheet direction to RTL
                $sheet->setRightToLeft(true);

                // Add title on the right
                $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'مشروع بناء');
                $sheet->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB('FF00B0F0');

                $sheet->getStyle('H1')->applyFromArray([
                    'font' => ['bold' => true, 'size' => 14],
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT]
                ]);

                // Add main title in the middle
                $sheet->setCellValue('E1', 'مواعيد شهر حزيران:');
                $sheet->getStyle('E1')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB('FF00B0F0');

                // Apply style to headers
                $headerStyle = [
                    'font' => ['bold' => true],
                    'alignment' => ['horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 'vertical' => Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER],
                    'fill' => [
                        'fillType' => Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                        'startColor' => ['rgb' => 'D9E1F2']  // Light blue color
                    ],
                    'borders' => [
                        'allBorders' => [
                            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => ['rgb' => '000000'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ];

                $sheet->getStyle('A3:' . $lastColumn . '3')->applyFromArray($headerStyle);

                // Apply borders to all data cells
                $sheet->getStyle('A3:' . $lastColumn . $lastRow)->applyFromArray([
                    'borders' => [
                        'allBorders' => [
                            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                            'color' => ['rgb' => '000000'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);

                // Apply left border to the entire data range (including headers)
                $sheet->getStyle('A3:A' . $lastRow)->applyFromArray([
                    'borders' => [
                        'left' => [
                            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_MEDIUM,
                            'color' => ['rgb' => '000000'],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);

                // Auto-size columns
                foreach (range('A', $lastColumn) as $column) {
                    $sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            },
        ];
    }
}

but since the predefined contains header and titles i tried to use $this->template = IOFactory::load(storage_path('templates/template.xlsx') and
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {
                $templateSheet = $this->template->getActiveSheet();
                $exportSheet = $event->sheet->getDelegate();

                // Copy styles from template to export sheet
                $this->copyStyles($templateSheet, $exportSheet);

                // Set RTL direction (if not already set in template)
                $exportSheet->setRightToLeft(true);

                // Auto-size columns (if not already set in template)
                foreach (range('A', 'J') as $column) {
                    $exportSheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            },
        ];
    }

    private function copyStyles(Worksheet $source, Worksheet $destination)
    {
        // Copy column widths
        foreach ($source->getColumnIterator() as $column) {
            $destination->getColumnDimension($column->getColumnIndex())->setWidth($source->getColumnDimension($column->getColumnIndex())->getWidth());
        }

        // Copy cell styles for the first 3 rows (adjust if needed)
        for ($row = 1; $row <= 3; $row++) {
            foreach (range('A', 'J') as $column) {
                $cell = $column . $row;
                $destination->getStyle($cell)->applyFromArray($source->getStyle($cell)->getStyleArray());
            }
        }

        // Copy merged cells
        foreach ($source->getMergeCells() as $mergeCell) {
            $destination->mergeCells($mergeCell);
        }
    }

i've got Too few arguments to function PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Style::getStyleArray(), 0 passed i don't know what should i use more i tried many solution i can't provide all here.

the problem seems on this line:
$destination->getStyle($cell)->applyFromArray($source->getStyle($cell)->getStyleArray());


You called getStyleArray method without argument. It should be an array of string or int like from the docs:
public getStyleArray(array<string|int, mixed> $array) : array<string|int, mixed>

I am not sure why you use that. If you don't have any idea why do you use that also, maybe you can just remove it. or add an empty array [].
However if you want to copy style you could use below code:
$source_style = $source->getStyle($cell);
$destination->duplicateStyle($source_style, $cell);


This solve the error but it didn't copy the template headers and color and image and title :(

@ArefMakke did you tried my code that use duplicateStyle method?
